# post form without refresh .net core mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a simple application in .NET Core MVC, with this simple form. When I try to post the form without refresh whole page only rest the form and got the result of done.

My code trial is:

```
 <form asp-area="" asp-controller="ContactUs" asp-action="UserMessage" data-ajax="true">
    <h5>Reach us quickly</h5>

    <div class="row">

        <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" name="UserName" placeholder="Enter name" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>

        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="row">
        <span asp-validation-for="Msg" class="text-danger"></span>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea asp-for="Msg" name="Msg" class="form-control" rows="7" cols="25" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn solid-btn" id="btnContactUs">
                Send Message
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and my action is:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserMessage(ContactUs model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(model);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

I want to change `return NoContent();` so I can show a message to the user that his message has sent or failed, without refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

Your form tag is missing some other ajax attributes:

```html
<form method="post"
        data-ajax="true"
        data-ajax-method="post"
        data-ajax-url="@Url.Page("UserMessage", "ContactUs")"
        data-ajax-loading="#loading"
        data-ajax-mode="replace"
        data-ajax-update="#updateDiv">

    <!-- form controls -->

    <button type="submit" class="btn solid-btn" id="btnContactUs">Send Message</button>
    <span id="loading" style="display:none;"> <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
</form>

<div id="updateDiv">
    <!-- ajax content will load here -->
    <!-- you can put the form inside this div -->
    <!-- so after submit the result will replace the form controls -->
</div>

<!-- include jquery libraries -->
@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive@3.2.6/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

The backend method can return the result as below:

```cs
public async Task<ContentResult> OnPostUserMessageAsync(ContactUs model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(model);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Content("done");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    return Content("something went wrong...");
}
```

See [Ajax Request Using Inline Attributes](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/AjaxRequest)

Comment: and then how can i handel the result in message ??

Comment: @mr.alaa I updated the answer, also you can see the Ajax Form sample in the link I sent

Comment: i got error InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'UserMessage' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page. If you are using LinkGenerator then you must provide the current HttpContext to use relative pages.

Comment: What is your project type? MVC or Razor Pages project?

Comment: Try to rename the method as in my reply

Comment: @mr.alaa this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to be replaced, you'll have to use ajax to post the data via javascript. Posting a form in a browser will replace the current html with the result of the controller, that's just how forms work.

It is also common practice to redirect any successful POST to a different page, so that the user can refresh that page without processing the POST request twice.

Comment: i didn't want to redirect to any other page and I was working with mvc before using dot net using ajax is too simple but I use  it in .net core not fire or do any sense and when it done  it return me back to a new page with json result only

Comment: For example, i can't use ajax. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for @Laz Ziya i have used his code and modify form to be

instead of

```
 <form method="post"
          data-ajax="true"
          data-ajax-method="post"
          data-ajax-url="@Url.Page("UserMessage", "ContactUs")"
          data-ajax-loading="#loading"
          data-ajax-mode="replace"
          data-ajax-update="#updateDiv">
```

to be

```
 <form asp-area="" asp-controller="ContactUs" asp-action="UserMessage" data-ajax-loading="#loading" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#updateDiv" data-ajax-success="Success" data-ajax-failure="Failure" data-ajax="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

for post form without refresh ,you need to use ajax in your code.